# Windows 10 - Close listening ports

Tags: windows, windows-10, netstat, ports

I'm doing a securisation of a PC with windows 10.

With the command:

```
"netstat -aon"
```

I get the list of all the active connections.
For some requirements I have to close the open port 80 and other open ports.

For example, the port 80 is in listening state with the following row:

```
Proto     Local Address    Foreign Address    State         PID
TCP       0.0.0.0:80       0.0.0.0:0          LISTENING     4
```

I tried to block the port 80 both in inbound and outbound rules in firewall but with netstat it continues to be in LISTENING state. The PID 4 is system task and stopping it I think is only a temporary solution.

Is there a way to close port 80 and the other ports I need to close?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Blocking in the Firewall prevents any external sources to access it, but it will not change what's running on your computer. You need to figure out what service/application is really listening to port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just blocking the traffic is not enough, you'll need to find what application / service is listening on the port.  Use `netstat -a -b` in an elevated session to see what that is.  Then you'll need to stop / disable that service or uninstall the application.

Keep in mind that a different application could at some point be installed to listen on the port, so keeping the firewall rules in place is still a good idea.  The firewall blocks the packets from being sent to or delivered from the port, but it doesn't stop a process from binding to a port and listening on it.

Answer (score 1):

An application can listen to a port, the firewall cannot prevent it from
listening.

The firewall can only prevent the port from being used to access,
or be accessed to/from outside of the computer.

To find which services can potentially listen on port 80,
run this command in CMD:

```
NET stop HTTP
```

You can answer `N` to the question
"Do you want to continue this operation?"
because the list is enough.

On my Windows 10 computer I get this list of system services:

```
Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)
World Wide Web Publishing Service
SSDP Discovery
Print Spooler
IIS Admin Service
Function Discovery Resource Publication
Function Discovery Provider Host
```

Some of these are services related to IIS, which is installed,
but you may check the services as listed on your computer.

Stop the services one at a time and see when the port is no longer
in the Listening state.

Comment: and final step, once you have identified and stopped the service that is responsible for the port creation, change its startup type to disabled or manual so it does not automatically restart again on next boot.